# как выйти из цикла и запустить его по новой?

Tags: python

имеется вот такой код:

```
import win32api
import time
import pyautogui

while True:
   l = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
   r = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)
 
   if (l<0 and r<0):  
      pyautogui.dragRel(-2,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-2,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-2,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-2,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-2,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-1,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-1,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-1,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-1,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(-1,4,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(1,3,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(1,3,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(1,3,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(1,3,duration=0.024)
      pyautogui.dragRel(1,3,duration=0.024)
```

Если зажать правую и левую кнопку мыши, курсор перемещается, но делает он это даже после того, как отпускаешь, а как сделать так, чтобы в момент отпускания левой кнопки мыши движение прекращалось? как бы **break**.

Однако если делать через **break**, то цикл уже не восстанавливается и не работает. Есть у вас идеи, господа?

Comment: Сделайте `debug` состояния левой кнопки мыши в момент нажатия и момент отпускания `win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)`. Вот это условие `if (l<0 and r<0)` у Вас явно при отпущенной левой кнопке продолжает срабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поместить ваш цикл в функцию, а в том месте где нужно запустить все заново сделайте  рекурсию с помощью return. Имейте ввиду, в пайтон количество рекурсий ограничено  до 1000 раз, если это действие будет чаще - используйте процессы для последующих перезапусков, и не забывайте удалять предыдущие процессы